# Unable to install Visual Studio express 2013 for windows desktop

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I had tried to install Visual Studio Express 2013 for windows desktop with update 4 on my laptop. My laptop has Windows 8.1(64 bit) installed, 4 GB RAM and 2.4 Ghz processor. I tried to installing from the .exe file which installs from the internet. After all files have been installed from net, it is showing me the following message:

> 'Setup successful. However, not all features installed correctly.'

It also says:

> 'Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Express LocalDB package failed'.

I tried to use the repair option but still no use. Please can you tell me what is the problem and how can I successfully install and launch the software?